# Use hover/active CSS by default on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

On desktop devices, I have designed my elements to be grayed out by default, but become colored when a user hovers over them. On mobile devices, I want them to use the hover state CSS to be colored in by default. Is it possible to do this through JavaScript?

I have lots of elements with different colors, so it would be much easier to simply trigger the state through JavaScript rather than writing new classes and adding them to the elements.

Comment: It is possible, but the question is why you need the hover state as default in mobile view? Assuming you cannot change this requirement, I would suggest you to add more classes to your CSS using media queries, rather than adding unwanted stylings or state triggers in JS and bloating up the code.

Answer (score 0):

No need for JS! You can use media queries in CSS to accomplish this.
Note: I'm using Bootstrap 4's numbers for screen sizes in this example:

```
.element:hover {
  background-color: gray
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .element {
    background-color: gray;
  }
}
```

Bootstrap starts medium screen sizes at 768px, hence my max width of 767. If you want, you can try it out at https://jsfiddle.net/21haxstd/